# SaaS with domain per user

Tags: apache, http, cakephp, dns, subdomain

I like to start a Software As A Servive application, that will offer domain registration for my clients, in order to allow the application access via their own registered domain.

The application will be builded with CakePHP. By accessing somebody the CakePHP Application, the CakePHP must recognize the client by the domain, and thus, to dispatch the client data.

To be more specific, lets say my SaaS is made for accountants. What I like to do, is to allow the accountants to use their own domain, to access the application.

The flow, may like something like that.

1. A visitor comes in my web site wich is "www.top-accountants.com"
2. He/she deside to register
3. In registration form I have a field saying "Enter your domain"
4. The user enters the domain : "www.local-accountants.com"
5. He/she completed the registration
6. Then, when somebody enter the domain "www.local-accountants.com" comes in my web server, and the server dispatch the accountant (my client) personal page

Another parameter, is to allow my clients to register either by using a sub domain so the above example can work like:

```
local-accountants.top-accountants.com
```

So, I have several questions:

1. Is it posible to map, domains to user accounts?
2. If so, how can I achive that?
3. The sub-domain will work in the same way with domains?
4. What is the best way to do the above?
5. Is there any specific name for the above technology I descrive in order to make my research ?

Kind regards...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll just go through your questions:

1. Not by Cake's default means.
2. You can always access the current (sub)domain by using PHP's environment variables, e.g. `_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"]`, and use that to choose a username upon login
3. On the PHP side, yes. Mind though that for registering top level domains, you'll always need a registrar (while you can administer subdomains with your own DNS server or your hoster's)
4. Go for subdomains and have your `UserController`'s `login` action determine the username from the subdomain.
5. No need for other technology. If you require strict separation of accounts, you'll need to go for per-subdomain deployments anyway (where you can then configure the "username" in the virtual host configuration)